# Establishing local network connection for both android and ios?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I want to make a simple messaging application for android and ios that uses RMI/TCP Connection. I've created such a thing before using Java RMI but I'm aware android os doesn't come with the native rmi library but I can use lipe. That said, even if I am able to create a local network based app for android it would be useless for my purposes if ios isn't able to join this network. I've looked through several threads but I have not been able to find a recent solution that would work for both. I'm doing this for a very niche use case I understand that otherwise such an endeavor would seem fruitless.

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a new local wifi network or you just want the apps to communicate over an existing local network that all of the devices are connected to?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear. Yes I want apps to be able to communicate over an existing local network. So basically users should be able to connect to an existing IP and connect to each other remotely.

Comment: So Zeroconf networking is probably the easiest. Apple's name for it is [Bonjour](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/). I am sure there are libraries for Android too.